# Meteor.js Chat - scrollToBottom(); only works from sending tab

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I was following this tutorial [chat-tutorial/chat-tutorial-part-4](https://github.com/meteor/chat-tutorial/blob/master/chat-tutorial-part-4.md) by rdickert, especially for the scrollToBottom function.

The purpose of this function is to scroll to bottom whenever a new message gets sent inside the chat. But right it only scrolls the tab from which the person sent it. Messages sent by other people (tabs) don't seem to trigger this function for the rest of the present users inside this chat room.

I tested it out with two tabs open, once in Chrome, second time I used the first tab in Chrome and another tab in Firefox. Same result both ways.

This is where I store the scrollToBottom-Function:

**imports/api/chat/chat.js**

```
var autoScrollingIsActive = false;
 scrollToBottom = function scrollToBottom (duration) {
  var messageWindow = $(".chatWindow");
  var scrollHeight = messageWindow.prop("scrollHeight");
  messageWindow.stop().animate({scrollTop: scrollHeight}, duration || 0);
};
```

Then, I want to use the function on the ui-part

**imports/ui/components/chat/chat.js**

This is the event where the message is getting actually sent by the user.

```
'keypress #text'(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    Meteor.call('chat.start', text, (error) => {
      if (error){
        alert(error.error);
      } 
      else {
        scrollToBottom(200);//Function triggers after msg is sent
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I also tried to trigger the scrollToBottom-Function with the onRendered-template, but it was the same outcome

```
 Template.message.onRendered(function () { 
  scrollToBottom(250);
 });
```

Could anyone explain to me whats the reason behind this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `onRendered` callback is triggered on each new message so it should work.

The problem might come from the scrolling function. Try to replace

```js
messageWindow.stop().animate({scrollTop: scrollHeight}, duration || 0);
```

with

```js
$('html').stop().animate({scrollTop: scrollHeight}, duration || 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the function is not scrolling on the html-tag, it's scrolling on a div called .chatWindow

Comment: Since .chatWindow is in the html tag and the scroll is on the whole page, it has the same effect.

Comment: I have reproduced the tutorial and it works fine. Try to log data in the onRendered callback to make sure it runs on receiving a new message.

Comment: I tried it with html, same result. When I tried to give out a console.log message, the console.log only appears when entering chatroom - means, when messages are rendered. Also, when I remove the scrollToBottom-call from the event-trigger it's not firing at the function at all from the onRendered-template.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found my error. I iterated the messages inside the message-template. Not inside the chatWindow-Template like instructed.

```
{{#each messages}}
{{> message}}
{{/each}}
```